# Build Spring ResponseEntity object from JSON string

Tags: java, json, spring, http, jackson

I have a valid JSON string of a `ResponseEntity.class`. Like this one:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Location": ["/v1/books/12345"]
    },
    "body": {
        "id": 12345,
        "type": "BOOK",
        "address": {
            "address": "Some address",
            "city": "Some city"
        }
    },
    "statusCode": "CREATED",
    "statusCodeValue": 201
}
```

I would like to create a `ResponseEntity.class` object from that string. I am using a standard Jackson mapper for that:

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, ResponseEntity.class)
```

And get back a following error:

```
Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Indeed, when I checked the class, I did not see a default constructor there. How can I solve the issue and create an object?

Comment: why do you need to convert it to `ResponseEntity` object?

Comment: @gohil90 String represents a cached response. If certain conditions are met, then I would like to return it directly from controller without doing any calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Jackson requires either a no arg constructor, or metadata to guide it.  see http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html

To get this to work with `ResponseEntity`, you'd probably need to extend `ResponseEntity`, re-declare the constructors (delegating to super) and annotate them as Jackson expects.

Comment: Tried that out, but did not succeeded. If you could provide an example, that would be perfect.